# Set display month in WPF Calendar control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I display my Calendar, I select a certain date by default:

```
myCalendar.SelectedDate = myDateTime;
```

The problem is that the month that is displayed doesn't change. It stays at the current month. I searched high and low for a way to display a certain month.

How can I force the Calendar to display the month that contains the selected date?

Comment: can you post more of your code.. also is there are you trying to assign the selected calendar to a variable...?

Comment: That is all the relevant code. I don't understand your question. I'm not assigning anything to a variable.

Comment: ok how about this since you only pasted a small snippet.. paste code where you declare myDateTime..

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text)` although it shouldn't really matter...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using the `DisplayDate` property? More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydate.aspx).